# Transferring MC Subscribers from old instance to a new one

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, subscriber-key

I just disconnected the MC connector from an old instance of Marketing Cloud and connected our new instance.  I have the contacts and leads syncing with SF in the new instance.  What is the best way to get the All Subscribers list into the new instance?

Specifically, if I export the subscribers from the old MC instance to a file, do I upload it to the new one with the Subscriber Key on it?  I don't want to create duplicates in Saleforce when I upload it.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You won’t create any duplicates, SFMC doesn’t synch All Subscribers data back to SF. Why do you want to transfer those subscribers, is it for maintaining the unsubscribes or something else?

Comment: Subscribers will be added to all subs as you send to them, unless you wanted to sync unsub status

Comment: Thanks for the insight - I thought should transfer them to maintain the unsubscribes since we are just using the new instance to essentially pick up where we are leaving off with the other one.  If there's no need to do that, maybe it's not worth the effort to import them.  Just didn't want to get blacklisted for not honoring unsubs since I have the unsub status on the contact and lead record in SF.  Will new sends honor the status in SF if the sends are from reports in SF?